# How do I properly use arrow functions to make this function output {say:"sticks",field:"awoo"}

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, arrow-functions

I don't understand how to make this type of chained arrow function work

The output of the function pop should be: {say:“sticks”,field:“awoo”}
With the input console.log(pop({say:"sticks"}));

I've tried setting the equivalence = (addObj) to no avail

```
let pop = (obj) => obj.say=="sticks" ? {field:"awoo"} : {field:"condensation"} => (addObj) => Object.assign(addObj,obj)

console.log(pop({say:"sticks"}));
console.log(pop({say:"dips"}));
```

/Users/pharris/test/app.js:3

```
let pop = (obj) => obj.say=="sticks" ? {field:"awoo"} : {field:"condensation"} = (addObj) => Object.assign(addObj,obj)
```

I've gotten these error messages

> SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target
>       at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: What does "work" mean? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Yes, can you please add exactly what the output should be?

Comment: the output should be {say:“sticks”,field:“awoo”}

Comment: And the function call?

Comment: with the function call pop({say:"sticks"}) or console.log(pop({say:"sticks"}));

Comment: Did I get it right? Also, do you need an explanation?

Comment: Where do the arrows in `=> (addObj) =>` come from, what did you intend to do with them? You shouldn't create another function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const pop = (obj) => 
  ({ say: obj.say, field: obj.say === 'sticks' ? 'awoo' : 'condensation' });

console.log(pop({say: 'sticks' }));
console.log(pop({say:"dips"}));
```

Comment: Thank you :) this works, is there any way to chain some type of function call to the end of the function that uses the newly made object?

Comment: Yeah, what do you want to accomplish with the next function?

Comment: Just be able to call anything with the information from the return value of the last function i.e console.log(newObject)

Comment: I need to see a complete sample of what you mean, the snippet already has a console log call and it addresses your original question. You should open another for the new question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is curried function. In the below program, it will return the required output as well as it will assign the object which got passed with this **result**,

```js
let result = {};

let pop = (obj) => {
  obj.field = obj.say=="sticks" ? "awoo" : "condensation";return (addObj) => Object.assign(addObj,obj)};

console.log(pop({say: 'sticks'})(result));
console.log(result);
```

So the **result** object is assigned with the **obj** values.